# Trying to get a fixed menu on top of page, but returning wrong Y position

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to create a programme page, this page consists of columns that you can expand by clicking on a button. When you get to a certain point on the programme a menu will appear and stay on top of the page. However, when you expand one of the columns, a problem will occur where the Y position isn't returned correctly. This makes the menu jump to the top of the page too early.

My Jquery knowledge is limited so I hope someone can help me with this. I've tried looking for an answer but unfortunately no results yet.

HTML:

```
<body>
<div id="column1">Expand this div and scroll down to see the problem</div>
<div id="fixed-row"></div>
<div id="column2"></div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
#column1{height:250px; width:200px; background-color:#545454; cursor:pointer; margin-bottom:5px; color:#fff;}

#column2{height:1000px; width:200px; background-color:#cecece;}

#fixed-row{height:50px; width:200px; background-color:#ff00ff; margin-bottom:5px;}

.fixed{position:fixed; top:0;}
```

JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$('#column1').click(function() {
    if ($('div#column1').height() > 251) {
        ($('div#column1').animate({height: '250px', navigation: true}))
    } else {
        ($('div#column1').animate({height: '500px', navigation: true}));
    }
});


    var top = $('#fixed-row').offset().top;

    $(window).scroll(function () {

    //Y position of scroll
    var y = $(window).scrollTop();

    //Whether below form
    if (y >= top) {

    //If so, add class fixed
    $('#fixed-row').addClass('fixed');
    }else {

    //Otherwise remove class fixed
    $('#fixed-row').removeClass('fixed');
    }

});

});
```

[I also created a JSfiddle to illustrate the problem](http://jsfiddle.net/jb36m/2/)

Many thanks in advance

Comment: update var top to the new offset.top after you call the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, you calculate `top` value before the animation, and do not update it afterwards. You need to update it when the animation is done.

Try something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var top = $('#fixed-row').offset().top;

$('#column1').click(function() {
    if ($('div#column1').height() > 251) {
        ($('div#column1').animate({height: '250px', navigation: true},function() { top = $('#fixed-row').offset().top; }));
    } else {
        ($('div#column1').animate({height: '500px', navigation: true},function() { top = $('#fixed-row').offset().top; }));
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your input! I found that the fix above was a bit easier to implement, but greatly appreciated!

Comment: Okay, glad you found the solution. However, keep in mind that upper solution (as it seems) works only when your elements start from the beginning of the page. If there is an offset from the top border, it will fail. If it works in your case, then it indeed is better solution if you don't care about performance issues.

Comment: It seems you're right... Changed best answer tag.. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

just change as below it works

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    var top = $('#column1').height();
//Y position of scroll
var y = $(window).scrollTop();

//Whether below form
if (y >= top) {

//If so, add class fixed
$('#fixed-row').addClass('fixed');
}else {

//Otherwise remove class fixed
$('#fixed-row').removeClass('fixed');
}   });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jb36m/4/

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thank you so much!